# Why does visual studio code add import statements that break my nodejs program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, visual-studio-code

I am developing backend on nodejs.

And I am experiencing weird annoying problem that is luring me for weeks:

Visual Studio Code adds import lines such as:

```
import { request } from 'http';
```

They appear randomly on startup, in beggining of my scripts and when they do, it produces compile errors on build. Something about 'module not found'..., but when I delete those lines, I can build without problem.

Anyone has any clue how to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "import" in the VS Code settings, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqnre.png) may be what your are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this fixed it.